# Help with filetype association!

Tags: python, filepath

I have the actual association part down, but when I open the file that is associated with my Python program, how do I get the filepath of the file opened?

I think it is something like sys.argv? But that just returns the path to the python program, not the associated file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of sys.argv are platform-dependent, as noted in [sys.argv](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.argv). I do know that `sys.argv[0]` is the full path on Windows only when you open `.py` files using the shell by double-clicking on it. Using the command line just results in the script name.

The `os` module provides platform-independent solutions. The full path to your script should always be available with the following code:

```
import os.path
import sys

print os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

The `__file__` attribute of your module looks what you're looking for.  E.g., save in `foo.py`:

```
$ cat foo.py
print 'Hello', __file__
$ python foo.py 
Hello foo.py
```

`os.path.abspath` will help you if you want the absolute rather than relative path, etc, etc.

Comment: Huh? I need the pathanme of the file I double clicked to open the program i.e. I double click file1.dgf and it opens prog.exe. How do I get the full path to file1.dfg?

Comment: You tagged your question as `python`, so what's `prog.exe` got to do with it?  Anyway, I suspect your question is strongly OS-dependent, and since you have no OS-related tags, I don't know whether the "association" is in Windows, MacOSX, KDE, Gnome, or what else.  Isn't your (python?) program getting the clicked file's path as `sys.argv[1]`?  It should, in these environments, but since I don't know your environment, it's hard to guess!-)

Comment: It is a Windows platform. Prog.exe is the Python program compiled to .exe, thus filetype association. It is only getting the path of itself when I use sys.argv[1], I'm not sure why.